# How to split in Spacy using doc phrase and extract a specific word

Tags: pandas, numpy, split, nlp, spacy

I have 5 phrases. For example:

`phrase(Text:'bla bla bla') | phrase(Text:'bla bla bla')|`

And I need to get what is after the Text label - which is in this case, "bla bla bla". So I've thought to use split, but without readline it's not possible. So how to extract it? Currently I get empty 5 lists.

I want a row with "bla bla bla| bla bla bla|...".

```
en_nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
en_nlp.add_pipe("textrank", config={ "stopwords": { "word": ["NOUN"] } })
doc = en_nlp(text)
tr = doc._.textrank

for phrase in doc._.phrases[:5]:
     print(phrase, end=" | ")

for phrase in doc._.phrases[:5]:    
    print(re.findall(r'Phrase\(Text:([^()]+)\)', text))
```

Comment: It sounds like it is best done with `re`, `import re` and use `print(re.findall(r'phrase\(Text:([^()]+)\)', text_string))`

Comment: what should be the text_string? it doesn't get the doc._.phrases[:5] as string

Comment: You have `text`

Comment: for phrase in doc._.phrases[:5]:
        print(re.findall(r'phrase\(Text:([^()]+)\)', text)) in this way I get empty 5 lists

Comment: You need no `for phrase in doc._.phrases[:5]:`. There is only one `text`. You do not need pandas nor spacy for this.

Comment: I have to use the phrase becouse I need the specifix texts from there and not from all the text. In all the text I have just text not Tags: 'bla bla bla'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I just needed to use `phrase.text` inside the loop and now it works.

```
print(phrase.text, end=" | ")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, in terms of the `"textrank"` pipeline component you're using, if you want to add an issue on our GitHub repo we may be able to help troubleshoot: https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank  Although without those terms being tagged by earlier parts of the spaCy pipeline, our pipeline component would not be likely to pick up these patterns.